# i'm using dropzone js.for file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

in knockout i'm try to upload file using dropzone js.

```
self.importCensus = function () {
        var dropZone = this;
        $(".preloader").css("height", $("#Wrapper").height() + 200);
        $(".preloader_outer").show();
        $("#ModalImportCensus").css("z-index", "999");
        var myDropzone = document.getElementById("dZUpload");
        var d = Dropzone.prototype.handleFiles(); //getting error
        var data = { groupState: self.CensusModel().Group().GroupState, groupZipCode: 
                     self.CensusModel().Group().ZipCode };
        $("#FileUploadForm").ajaxSubmit({
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
            }
```

which function i need to useso that on click event i can get upload file on c#

```
<form id="FileUploadForm" action="/employee/upload" class="mb0 form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div id="dZUpload" class="dropzone">
        <div class="dz-default dz-message"></div>                 
   </div>
```

i'm using this for `fileupload.On` c# page i get nothing

```
[HttpPost]
  public string upload(FormCollection from)
  {
      HttpPostedFileBase httpFile = Request.Files["file"];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not knockout related, you just use the instructions from the plugin makers for adding this to your website as normal, if you follow there instructions, and if there is anything custom to do,  you can do this in the config